# Can A View Load All Data, And Filter (Hide) With CSS?

Tags: views

When using an exposed filter in a view, any data that doesn't meet the filter is removed from the page. Partially for SEO reasons, I'd like all the data to load (and stay in the HTML), but then the exposed filters will simply use CSS to hide the data that doesn't match the filter.

Does that make sense? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean the rows generated by the views to be hidden or the available options on the exposed filters? In either case I don't see how this can be done only by css, meaning I think you might want to use a specific hook and/or some javascript or jquery

Comment: Yes, the rows generated. And I'm sure you're right, it will need some kind of JS. Something that functions like https://getuikit.com/docs/switcher.html. Or even a "tabbed" UI of some sort...?

Comment: Well let me just add that you can use hook_views_pre_render to hide the rows that don't meet your criteria BUT if your rows are affected by the exposed filter I don't see how the pre-render hook will help you at all. On that case you might use hook_views_query_alter to alter the query before is submitted and the use pre render but this is actually something out of my knowledge...Now as I can understand from your comment I guess a js or jquery way is more suitable to your case but I cannot input any valuable info...sorry, this is my two cents for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a rather complicated arrangement of views inside of views. I was already using a Bootstrap child theme, so I used Pills and Data-Toggles (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). Global text areas (and some custom template markup) allowed me to create the markup that Bootstrap wanted. I'm sure there's a smarter and better "Drupal way", but this got me exactly what I wanted using already available Bootstrap code.

Thanks everyone for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

#### A module might be able to help you with this

https://drupal.org/project/mixitup_views (drupal 7 + 8)
Loads all items and might be close to what you need

https://www.drupal.org/project/isotope (drupal 7 + 8) A highly customizable module that is probably harder to implement as well

#### Some other alternative modules

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_semantic_tabs (drupal 8) might be a good fit

https://drupal.org/project/shuffle (drupal 8)
Not sure if it loads all results at once but it offers the filtering you described

https://drupal.org/project/views_quicksand (drupal 7)
does not load all results at once by has the filtering effect that you need so it might be a starting point

**NOTE:** all or almost all above module use JS libraries that you have to pay for if you implement them in commercial products

#### A custom alternative

Create a view that displays all results
and use global text area to rewrite all the elements to be part of a container div
and add classes to the container based on the categories you want filterable

Then use this code https://codepen.io/terf/post/jquery-filter-divs
in your custom module or theme changing `box` class with your container's class name